# Retrieve users from Firestore within a range using GeoFireStore Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, geofirestore

In my Android application, I need to get a list with users from **Firestore** within a range using **GeoFireStore**.

Database structure in Firestore:
[image]

All the information I got from this [link](https://github.com/imperiumlabs/GeoFirestore-Android).

Dependency:

```
implementation 'com.github.imperiumlabs:GeoFirestore-Android:v1.1.1'
```

Repositories:

```
maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
```

A code:

```
CollectionReference geoFirestoreRef = 
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Users");
GeoFirestore geoFirestore = new GeoFirestore(geoFirestoreRef);

GeoQuery geoQuery = geoFirestore.queryAtLocation(new GeoPoint(32.848971, 35.0920935), 30);

geoQuery.addGeoQueryDataEventListener(new GeoQueryDataEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDocumentEntered(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, GeoPoint location) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onDocumentExited(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {  
    }

    @Override
    public void onDocumentMoved(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, GeoPoint location) { 
    }

    @Override
    public void onDocumentChanged(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, GeoPoint location) {    
    }

    @Override
    public void onGeoQueryReady() {     
    }

    @Override
    public void onGeoQueryError(Exception exception) {
    }
});
```

So I didn't do I can't to call a function:

```
@Override
public void onDocumentEntered(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, GeoPoint location) {
}
```

Only this function is called:

```
@Override
public void onGeoQueryReady() {     
}
```

Comment: What is happening when you are using this code?

Comment: Happening call a function `onGeoQueryReady()`

Comment: No, what is happening in terms of error. What is the behaviour when using the above code?

Comment: I do not receive a list of users from the Firestore within the established range. (radius)

Comment: Are you sure that you have the correct coordinatest and that users are within that rage? Please also add your database strucuture as a screenshot.

Comment: Yes, I sure that coordinate and that users are within that rage. So already have a screenshot, this is the **Database structure in Firestore**. What do you want to see?

Comment: I cannot see the geohash in your object.

Comment: How I can add a geohash?

Comment: Is added when you add a location, however it is not present in your database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm adding this as an answer because I can't add comments.

So, what you're trying to do is getting all the `DocumentSnapshots` within a certain radius, for this your code is correct, you create a new `GeoFirestore` instance using a `CollectionReference`, and then you query the location you want.

The problem is that **in your database** currently there is **no location data** usable by GeoFirestore; you can solve this by **appending the "location data" when you add your document to the database**.

```java
implementation 'com.github.imperiumlabs:GeoFirestore-Android:v1.2.0'
/*
 * You have to do this only one time for document
 * so the best is after the document upload to Firestore.
 */

//The id of the document you want to add the location
String documentId = documentReference.id;
GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(/*lat,long of your point*/);
geoFirestore.setLocation(documentId, point);
```

You can find the official documentation [here](https://github.com/imperiumlabs/GeoFirestore-Android#setting-location-data).

As the last tip, I suggest you update the library to the correct version (1.2.0) because the geo hashing algorithm is changed and you can take advantage of the kotlin capability.

Answer (score 0):

So, as Alex said, I missed GeoHash in my database. This is correct.

A code convert location to a hash:

```
GeoHash geoHash = new GeoHash(32.9235234, 35.3310622);
String res = geoHash.getGeoHashString();
```

result:

> res = svc57cx33m

But for all this to work, you need to properly store data in **Firestore**.

How to store geo data correctly in **Firestore** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56034936/data-structure-in-firestore-using-geofirestore/56035955#56035955).