# Data structure in Firestore using GeoFirestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, geofirestore

I write an Android application and use **GeoFirestore**.

I can't to get a list with users from **Firestore** within a range 30 meters.

I think that I wrong to make a structure of data.

Data Structure:

[image]

Did I build my data structure correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved my problem.

My structure of data is not correct.

The correct structure in the picture below:

[image]

*geoHash* - **String**

*location* - **Array**

In *array* type of data is **Number**.

Comment: is l stored as geopoint or array of latitude and longitude? the documentation says is l is  a geopoint

Comment: Hi @RLShyam. You can see the data structure in an image above. Yes, you need to save coordinates (latitude and longitude) to an array with the name "l".